Conveying a mathematical joke
I want to convey the following mathematical joke about a supposed dialogue between the imaginary unit (i^2=-1) and the (irrational) number π.

I would convey 'Be rational' by 'Sois rationnel' (nevertheless, the imperative sois sounds more formal to my native ears than be).
I have posted a related question about get real.
Conveying "I mean come on let's get real"
I think in the context of this joke 'get real' could be conveyed by 'Sois réel' to keep the joke. What do you think?

I think the joke depends too much on the language. Like the joke with the snakes on the ark. -- While the animals leave the ark, Noah says to each pair "go forth and multiply". Two snakes however reply "we can't, we're adders!" Noah is confused, but he has to tend to the next pair so he let's it slip. A few days later, while exploring the drying lands, Noah steps over a fallen tree and sees the adders in the process of...well, multiplying. "I thought you can't multiply?" -- "We can so by logs!"

C'est peut-être difficile dans ce format très succinct, car "get real" est trop idiosyncratique en anglais, sans équivalent véritable en français (en deux mots): réel serait le bon mot à utiliser pour les nombres réels, mais nous n'avons pas vraiment l'expression "sois réel".
Peut-être, mais ce n'est pas terrible: "un peu de rationalité", et la réponse "un peu de réalisme". Ou bien "un peu de rationalité/moins de complexité". Mais je pense qu'il va falloir travailler au delà d'une traduction immédiate.

Je me risque pas à rédiger une réponse parce que je ne suis pas sure d'avoir compris (même en anglais, j'ai pas les bases en maths), c'est l'hôpital qui se moque de la charité, non ? un nombre irrationnel qui s'adresse à pi lui aussi nbre irrationnel ?).  Sois réel ça ne marche pas bien sûr, mais est-ce que réaliste passerait – T'es pas rationnel – Et toi, t'es pas réaliste. Ou alors, – Sois donc rationnel – (Et toi), sois donc réaliste.

@None oui, ça pourrait marcher avec réaliste, mais c'est moins croquant qu'en anglais...

@none Pi est un nombre réel mais irrationnel (ce n'est pas le résultat d'une division de deux entiers). i demande à Pi d'être rationnel, ce qu'il n'est pas et Pi répond à i, soit réel, ce qu'il n'est pas non plus car c'est un nombre imaginaire (ni rationnel, ni irrationnel, ni réel). La blague est donc que chaque nombre demande l'impossible à l'autre et joue sur le double sens puisque ce dialogue a aussi un sens en anglais de tous les jours.

@Frank Qqch comme "Bienvenue dans le monde réel".

@Frank ya aussi, au-delà d'une traduction immédiate, "Sois rationnel. - Et dans les conseils transcendants, t'as quoi? ".

@FrançoisJurain Pas mal! Bien vu.
